# How to check if user input is a float or int in java?

Tags: java, floating-point, integer, java.util.scanner

I need to write a Java program to ask the user to input a number from the keyboard. The output should indicate whether it is positive or negative, a floating number or an integer, an even number or an odd number. USING ONLY IF...ELSE statements.

Here is my code so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PracticeClass1 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter a number: ");

    int number = keyboard.nextInt();
    float Number = keyboard.nextFloat();

    if (number >= 1)
        System.out.print(number + " is a positive,");
    else 
        System.out.print(number + " is a negative,");

    if (number%2 == 0 )
        System.out.print(" even number");
    else 
        System.out.print(" odd number ");

    if (keyboard.hasNextInt()) 
        System.out.print(" is an integer");

    if (keyboard.hasNextFloat()) 
        System.out.println(" is a floating number");

    }
}
```

Comment: A little off-topic but only integers can be considered to be odd or even.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a straightforward solution that treats the input as a float and then check separately if it is an into or a float and stores that in a local variable

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter a number: ");

boolean isInt = false;
if (keyboard.hasNextFloat()) {
    float number = keyboard.nextFloat();
    if (number == (int) number) {
        isInt = true;
    }
    boolean isPositive = false;
    if (number > 0.0) {
        isPositive = true;
    }

    if (isInt) {
        int intNumber = (int) number;
        System.out.print(intNumber + " is an integer");
        if (number % 2 == 0)
            System.out.print(" and is even");
        else
            System.out.print(" and is odd");
    } else
        System.out.print(number + " is a floating number");

    if (isPositive)
        System.out.print(" and is positive");
    else
        System.out.print(number + " and is negative");
} else {
    System.out.println("Not a number");
}
```

Comment: `+1` for this nice answer. Just two feedbacks: (1) Do not close `Scanner` for `System.in` as it will also close `System.in` and there will be no way to open it again. It can be a problem if the program has to process further inputs. (2) Change `number + " and is negative"` to `" and is negative"` for a clean output for a negative number. In addition to being clean, it will also avoid confusion e.g. if you enter `-10` currently, it will show: `-10 is an integer and is even-10.0 and is negative` which not only looks ugly but is also confusing.

Answer (score 1):

By the time you call `keyboard.hasNextInt()` and `keyboard.hasNextFloat()`, you have already gotten the input, meaning these methods have nothing to check.

Instead, perform this before getting the number and store the result in a `boolean`:

```
System.out.println("Enter a number: ");

boolean isInt = keyboard.hasNextInt();
// Also get rid of the two input prompts, so you don't need to enter 2 numbers,
// of which only the first one would be used.
float number = keyboard.nextFloat();

// Perform other checks

if(isInt)
    System.out.println((int) number + " is an int");
else
    System.out.println(number + " is an float");
```

Comment: This is incorrect since every `int` is a `float`. The else will never be reached.

Comment: @HarshalParekh You're right, should've payed more attention to that. I've changed it to `hasNextInt`, which should  solve the problem.